# Как сделать чтобы можно было скрыть/показать элемент при нажатии на кнопку и чтобы происходило внутри родителя кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно при нажатии на .jobs_more скрыть/показать .jobs_descript_full но чтобы закрывало только в своем .job_item . + по дефолту jobs_descript_full был скрыт. (JQuery)

```html
<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Корректировка проекта полигона твердых отходов ПАО «Распадская»</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Сбор и анализ исходных данных, обоснование технических и технологических решений по объекту «Корректировка проекта полигона твердых отходов ПАО «Распадская».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>

<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» рудника месторождения «Юбилейное»</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Научно-исследовательская работа (НИР) от 28 июля 2021 г. «Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевой» ООО «Башкирская медь» месторождение «Юбилейное» и сопряжений ствола с горизонтами».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>

<div class="job_item">

  <p class="jobs_title">Расчет крепи ствола шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» Ново-Учалинского подземного рудника</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript">Научно-исследовательская работа (НИР) от 22 июля 2021 г. «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту «АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации «ОАО
    «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год».</p>
  <p class="jobs_descript_full">В рамках реализации специальных технических условий (СТУ) на проектирование объекта АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая» в составе проектной документации АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник.
    Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год выполнен Отчет от 22 июля 2021 г. о НИР «Расчет крепи и корректировка параметров армирования крепи по объекту АО «Учалинский ГОК». Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Ствол шахты «Скипо-Клетевая»
    в составе проектной документации ОАО «Учалинский ГОК» Ново-Учалинский подземный рудник. Отработка запасов месторождения на полное развитие - 4,5 млн. т/год». В ходе расчета осуществлена проверка несущей способности крепи и оптимизация параметров армирования
    на участках пород, отнесенных к IV категории устойчивости.
  </p>
  <a class="jobs_more">Подробнее <span><ion-icon name="chevron-down-outline"></ion-icon></span></a>

</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Вешаем обработчик клика на все ссылки .jobs_more, при клике берем именну ту на которой произошло событие $(this),находим непосредственно ее родителя parents('.job_item'), и в родителе находим необходимое описание find('.jobs_descript_full') и тоглим класс "show"

```
$('.jobs_more').click(function () {
   $(this).parents('.job_item').find('.jobs_descript_full').toggleClass('show');
})
```

В css добавьте правила:

```
.jobs_descript_full {
   display: none;
}

.jobs_descript_full.show {
   display: block;
}
```